# Lexer for shell-like language [rust]

Tags: rust, shell, sh, lexical-analysis

I am working on writing a rust implementation of a `sh`-like language.
Rather than posting 600 lines of code here, you can just go to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ardaku/qiish-lex).

Is this a good approach for lexxing?

Here's the lex function:

````rust
pub fn lex(&mut self) {
    while self.input.has_next() {
        let c: char = self.input.next();
        match c {
            /// Any whitespace is ignored.
            ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' => {
                continue;
            }

            /// Comments can also be ignored.
            '#' => {
                while self.input.has_next() && self.input.next() != '\n' {
                    self.input.next();
                }
                continue;
            }

            // Redirection
            '>' => {
                if self.input.has_next() {
                    match self.input.lookahead(1) {
                        '>' => {
                            self.input.next();
                            self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::RedirAppend));
                        }

                        '|' => {
                            self.input.next();
                            self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::ForceRedir));
                        }

                        _ => {
                            // We shouldn't eat the next token if it's anything else,
                            // it just means that the code either has a space afterwords
                            // or it's (potentially) important text
                            self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Redir));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Pipes
            '|' => {
                self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Pipe));
            }

            '{' => {
                self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::LeftCurlyBrace));
            }

            '}' => {
                self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::RightCurlyBrace));
            }

            '[' => {
                if self.input.has_next() && self.input.lookahead(1) == '[' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output
                        .push(Token::new(TokenType::LeftDoubleSquareBracket));
                } else {
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::LeftSquareBracket));
                }
            }

            ']' => {
                if self.input.has_next() && self.input.lookahead(1) == ']' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output
                        .push(Token::new(TokenType::RightDoubleSquareBracket));
                } else {
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::RightSquareBracket));
                }
            }

            '(' => {
                if self.input.has_next() && self.input.lookahead(1) == '(' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::LeftDoubleParen));
                } else {
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::LeftParen));
                }
            }
            ')' => {
                if self.input.has_next() && self.input.lookahead(1) == ')' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::RightDoubleParen));
                } else {
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::RightParen));
                }
            }

            // Keywords and identifiers
            'a'..='z' | 'A'..='Z' | '_' => {
                if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 'c'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "ase"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Case));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(5)
                    && c == 'c'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(5) == "oproc"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Coproc));
                } else if self.input.has_next() && c == 'd' && self.input.lookahead(1) == 'o' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Do));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 'd'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "one"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Done));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 'e'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "lif"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Elif));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 'e'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "lse"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Else));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 'e'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "sac"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Esac));
                } else if self.input.has_next() && c == 'f' && self.input.lookahead(1) == 'i' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Fi));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(2)
                    && c == 'f'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(2) == "or"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::For));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(7)
                    && c == 'f'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(7) == "unction"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Function));
                } else if self.input.has_next() && c == 'i' && self.input.lookahead(1) == 'f' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::If));
                } else if self.input.has_next() && c == 'i' && self.input.lookahead(1) == 'n' {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::In));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(5)
                    && c == 's'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(5) == "elect"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Select));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 't'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "hen"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Then));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(3)
                    && c == 't'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(3) == "ime"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Time));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(4)
                    && c == 'u'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(4) == "ntil"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Until));
                } else if self.input.has_next_multi(4)
                    && c == 'w'
                    && self.input.lookahead_multi(4) == "hile"
                {
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.input.next();
                    self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::While));
                } else {
                    let mut tk: String = "".to_owned();
                    while self.input.has_next() {
                        match self.input.next() {
                            'a'..='z' | 'A'..='Z' | '_' | '0'..='9' => {
                                tk.push(c);
                                self.input.next();
                            }
                            _ => {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Text));
                    }
                }
            }

            _ => {
                panic!("Can't handle character {}", c)
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

- A method `self.input.discard(n)` would be very helpful. Consider

  ```
            } else if self.input.has_next_multi(5)
                && c == 'c'
                && self.input.lookahead_multi(5) == "oproc"
            {
                self.input.discard(5);
                self.output.push(Token::new(TokenType::Coproc));
  ```
- I don't think `has_next_multi` has a reason to exist. `lookahead_multi` is in the position to fail if there is not enough characters in the stream.
- Matching `c` looks like a premature optimization. Just lookahead for all possible alternative, like `>>`, `>|`, `>`, etc. It is also recommended to keep them in a table, and iterate over it.
- I see no separators. An identifier `case1` will be tokenized into a keyword `case` and an identifier `1`. I don't think it is correct.
- Along the same line, consider a redirection into a file named `case`. The code will recognize a file name as a keyword. Keep it in mind before diving into a parser.
- There is no support for quotes, backslash, or any other escape mechanism.